# Electric oven Temperature

Tags: temperature

I have bought a Smeg double oven to replace my old smeg oven.  As I have read the temperatures fluctuate which I can understand. An engineer came and tested it and said it was operating 10 deg below the stated temp on dial overal on both ovens. On receiving the report smeg have state that the ovens are working to specification.  Can anyone advise.  Thank you

Comment: Um, what are you actually asking here?

Comment: [don't worry, be happy](http://www.thekitchn.com/why-you-should-stop-worrying-about-your-oven-temperature-175602)

Answer (score 3):

I'd advise you to turn your oven up 10 degrees when using it, and get an oven thermometer.

Answer (score 2):

Most oven's specifications provide a range of temperatures you might see for a given setting. Calibrating them perfectly would prsumably add significantly to the cost. My oven claims to have a range of +/- 25 F, so I don't think being 10 degrees off (C or F) is anything to worry about. Just compensate when setting the temperature.